# C# Error: variable bit used as method

Tags: c#

I got the following error:

> view( 'rs' is a variable bit it is used as a 'method')

I don't understand why. Please kindly advise. Thank you!

```
public void loadFirst()
{
    ListView1.Items.Clear();
    Connection connect = new Connection();
    ADODB.Recordset rs = new ADODB.Recordset();
    var _with2 = connect;
    _with2.open();
    string SQL = "SELECT * FROM CA";
    rs.Open(SQL, _with2.conn, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic);
    if (rs.RecordCount != 0) 
    {
        while (!rs.EOF) {
            ListViewItem lv =      ListView1.Items.Add(rs("ProjectName").Value);
            lv.SubItems.Add(rs("ItemName").Value);
            lv.SubItems.Add(rs("Amount").Value);
            lv.SubItems.Add(rs("Budget").Value);
            lv.SubItems.Add(rs("Expenses").Value);
            lv.SubItems.Add(rs("Total").Value);                               
            rs.MoveNext();
        }
    }
    _with2.close();
}
```

Comment: `rs("ProjectName")` is invoking a method on `rs`. Maybe it should be `rs["ProjectName"]` instead? Also - please format/indent your code before posting here

Comment: The answer lies in the question, rs is a variable, it is created by the new ADODB.RecordSet(); but when called, you are calling it like it is a method, func or action. Without knowing the complete library i am not going to put as an answer, however, i would suggest instead of rs("ProjectName") you try rs["ProjectName"]

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you need to use square brackets when accessing indexer property of the `ADODB.Recordset rs` object. For example, instead of `rs("Budget")` use `rs["Budget"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using either of these.

```
string val = (string)rs.Fields["ProjectName"].Value; // using column name.
```

or

```
string val = rs.Fields[1].Value.ToString(); // using index
```

Answer (score 0):

(...) after an identifier signals that the identifier is a function and that the items between the brackets are the actual values for the parameters of the function.

[MSDN C# operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/6a71f45d.aspx) defines that () is a function invocation operator

rs is the identifier an object, an instance of a class. It is not a function, you can't use (...).

Perhaps you are looking for the index property. Square brackets signal that the object can be considered as a sequence of items where the value between the square brackets can be uses as an index. Common uses of the square brackets are the integer indexes in arrays, lists, collections, but the value between the square brackets doesn't have to be an integer. When using a Dictionary the type between the brackets is a value of the key type.

AdobDb.Recordset also has an index property [click to view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675255(v=vs.85).aspx). Maybe you wanted to call this one?